# Populating drop downs based on previous drop down (from nested JSON)

Tags: jquery, json

I'm looping through some JSON and populating a drop down with all the Publishers (irrespective of genre).

My code for this is:

```
//Populate the Publisher
      function populatePublishers(){
      var myData = JSON.parse($RetrievedData);
     $(myData.genre).each(function (i) {
           $(this.publishers).each(function (i) {
            getUnique(this);   
           });
           });
     };

//find only unique publishers
     function getUnique(option) {
        var optionExists = $("#comboPublisher").find("option[value='" + option.publisher + "']").length > 0;
        if (!optionExists) {
            $("#comboPublisher").append($("<option/>", {
                val: option.publisher,
                html: option.publisher
            }));
            $('#comboPublisher').selectpicker("refresh");
        }};
```

What i'm now trying to do it return the games for a selected publisher.  So the comboPublisher box shows ALL the publishers, a user selects say Blizzard and the next drop down would contain Starcraft and Diablo.

I attempted this:

```
  function populateGames(){
  var myData = JSON.parse($RetrievedData);
 $(myData.genre).each(function (i) {
       $(this.publishers).each(function (i) {
           $(this.games).each(function(i){
        uniqueOptions2(this);   
       });
       });
 })};
```

But it returns ALL the games and not just the ones by the selected publisher.  Any ideas how i can achieve it?

My Json is in the following format:

```
{"genres": [{
        "genre": "RPG",
        "publishers": [{
            "publisher": "Square",
            "games": [{
                "game": "FFX",
                "rating": [
                    12, 15
                ]
            }]
        }, {
            "publisher": "Blizzard",
            "games": [{
                "game": "Starcraft",
                "rating": [
                    10, 12
                ]
            }, {
                "game": "Diablo",
                "rating": [
                    15
                ]
            }, ]
        }]
    }, {
        "genre": "Action",
        "publishers": [{
            "publisher": "EA",
            "games": [{
                "game": "COD",
                "rating": [
                    18, 20
                ]
            }, {
                "game": "Titanfall",
                "rating": [
                    18
                ]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

By Default ALL should be selected for Games and Rating's when  a publisher is selected

Comment: Why the downvote?  Would be helpful to know to avoid it next time

Comment: No one able to advise?